# Is it possible to alter a table to include reference to an upstream table in datajoint for python?

Tags: alter, datajoint

We want to alter a table to include a non-primary key reference to a new table. The old definition is:

```
@schema
class SpikeSortingParameters(dj.Manual):
    definition = """
    # Table for holding parameters for each spike sorting run
    -> SortGroup
    -> SpikeSorterParameters
    -> SortInterval
    ---
    -> SpikeSortingMetrics
    -> IntervalList
    import_path = '': varchar(200) # optional path to previous curated sorting output
    """
```

We'd like to add

```
-> SpikeSortingArtifactParameters
```

as a non primary key, and before we spent time trying to get this to work, we wanted to know if it was possible given that we don't know of a way to assign a default value here.

thanks in advance...

Loren

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, foreign key updates are not currently supported with `table.alter()`. There is a workaround that can be used but there are a few steps and those should be taken carefully. It would be best to file this as a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/issues/new/choose).

### Using Alter

For instance, consider the following:

If you have 2 tables defined as follows:

```py
import datajoint as dj

schema = dj.Schema('rguzman_alter_example')

@schema
class Student(dj.Lookup):
    definition = """
    student_first_name: varchar(30)
    student_last_name: varchar(30)
    ---
    student_location: varchar(30)
    """
    contents = [('Joe', 'Schmoe', 'Los Angeles, CA'), ('Suzie', 'Queue', 'Miami, FL')]

@schema
class Assignment (dj.Lookup):
    definition = """
    assignment_id: int
    ---
    assignment_due_date: date
    #-> [nullable] Student # Standard way to define a foreign key on secondary attributes with NULL as default
    """
    contents = [dict(assignment_id=100, assignment_due_date='2021-04-21')]
```

Now suppose that you'd like to have a foreign key on secondary attributes with `NULL` as the default. You can pass options to foreign keys in secondary attributes (see the comment above where we allow it to default to `NULL`). Initializing a table from scratch in this way works just fine. For the case where we want to add a foreign key on a secondary attribute after a table has been initialized with existing data, `Assignment.alter()` would be the best means to achieve this so long as we establish a default value to fill existing records with. Let's see what happens when we uncomment the foreign key on secondary attributes, redefine the `Assignment` table class, and try to alter.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-09997168281c> in <module>
----> 1 Assignment.alter()

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datajoint/table.py in alter(self, prompt, context)
     84             del frame
     85         old_definition = self.describe(context=context, printout=False)
---> 86         sql, external_stores = alter(self.definition, old_definition, context)
     87         if not sql:
     88             if prompt:

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datajoint/declare.py in alter(definition, old_definition, context)
    367         raise NotImplementedError('table.alter cannot alter the primary key (yet).')
    368     if foreign_key_sql != foreign_key_sql_:
--> 369         raise NotImplementedError('table.alter cannot alter foreign keys (yet).')
    370     if index_sql != index_sql_:
    371         raise NotImplementedError('table.alter cannot alter indexes (yet)')

NotImplementedError: table.alter cannot alter foreign keys (yet).
```

Oh, there's an exception... So it turns out that it is not implemented yet for this use case. However, there *is* a manual workaround that can be leveraged so let me detail those steps until there is support.

### Workaround

1. Instead of defining the foreign key on secondary attributes as above, define it in this way:

   ```py
   @schema
   class Assignment (dj.Lookup):
       definition = f"""
       assignment_id: int
       ---
       assignment_due_date: date
       {newline.join(['' + a.name + '=null: ' + a.type for a in Student.heading.attributes.values() if a.in_key])}
       """
       contents = [dict(assignment_id=100, assignment_due_date='2021-04-21')]
   ```

   This 'copies' over the primary attributes of the parent table into the secondary attributes of your child table.
2. Perform alter as normal: `Assignment.alter()`
3. Manually add the foreign key using a SQL query directly. Like this:

   ```py
   q = """
       ALTER TABLE {table}
       ADD FOREIGN KEY ({fk})
       REFERENCES {ref} ({pk})
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
       ON DELETE RESTRICT
       """.format(table=Assignment.full_table_name,
                  fk=','.join([f'`{k}`' for k in Student.primary_key]),
                  ref=f'`{Student.table_name}`',
                  pk=','.join([f'`{k}`' for k in Student.primary_key]))
   dj.conn().query(q)
   ```
4. Make sure to remove the portion that was added in step 1 and replace it with the proper specification i.e. `-> [nullable] Student`
5. Restart your kernel
6. To verify it has been properly set, check `Assignment.describe()`. If everything worked properly, the result should be:

   ```py
   assignment_id        : int                          
   ---
   assignment_due_date  : date                         
   -> [nullable] Student
   ```

   Additionally, any pre-existing records should now be prefilled with `NULL`.